# Inject multitouch gestures in Android via /dev/uinput

Tags: android, linux, root, multi-touch

I am looking for a way to inject multitouch gestures into Android. So far I open /dev/uinput and write to the file-descriptor. This solution works for "one" touch. How to inject multi-touch inputs?

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, `/dev/uinput` for touch gestures is going to be tough. I implemented single touch, which worked only on some devices. On others, it would just have the effect of "hover".

I then used android's touch device `/dev/input/eventX` (which you can, if you have root access). The best way to see how touch input is working is to use `getevent /dev/input/eventX` binary on the device itself. The [linux multitouch protocol](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/multi-touch-protocol.txt)input describes the multi-touch features and behaviour quite nicely and gives good background on what you will see with `getevent` after you decipher the hex codes (and translate them to something more meaningful like `ABS_MT_POSITION_X`).

In short:

1. Find out which of the `/dev/input/eventX` devices is touch input device. It is a device, which registered ABS_MT_* events. You can see this with `getevent -il` command (run in `adb shell`)
2. Say that the input device which supports such events is `/dev/input/event2`.
3. Issue `getevent /dev/input/event2` command from `adb shell` and touch the screen.
4. You will get some output on screen, which contains three columns:

   1. event category (for `EV_ABS`, this is `0003`)
   2. event code (for `ABS_MT_SLOT` this is `0x002f`
   3. event value (which is slot number, coordinate, pressure, or whatever the event defines)
5. See how the events look like and just replay them. You will be able to inject multi-touch events and gestures this way.

For instace, annotated output of `getevent /dev/input/event2` for double tap:

```
0003 002f 00000001 // slot 1 (finger 1)
0003 0039 000019fe // tracking id for slot 1
0003 0035 00000146 // position x
0003 0036 00000117 // position y
0003 0030 00000033 // touch area
0000 0000 00000000 // sync
0003 002f 00000000 // slot 0 (finger 0)
0003 0039 000019ff // tracking id for slot 0
0003 0035 000000cb // position x
0003 0036 00000164 // position y
0003 0030 00000028 // touch area
0000 0000 00000000 // sync
0003 0039 ffffffff // relese finger 0
0000 0000 00000000 // sync
0003 002f 00000001 // slot 1
0003 0039 ffffffff // release finger 1
0000 0000 00000000 // sync
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will even work but (I'm assuming you're doing this from an app) you could have a series of AsyncTasks that run at the same time (and write to /dev/uinput) to simulate simulataneous touches